# How to read a text file with multiple data types and store them in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read a text file of various data and getting it stored into an Array, so that after receiving user input I can compare it to see if there are any matches inside the Array.

example text:

```
1A 1st true false false 28.50 free  
2B 2nd false true false 25.00 free  
3C 3rd true true false 32.50 free
```

As you can see I'm dealing with Strings, booleans and a double.

I initially tried reading the file and storing each line as a String in a String Array but that didn't work when I then needed to compare the user input.

So I then tried to create an Array and a sub-array like below:

```
    try {
        File read = new File("seats.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(read);
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String dataRead = reader.nextLine();
            
            String[] seatData = dataRead.split(" ");
            
            String seatID = seatData[0];
            String seatClass = seatData[1];
            boolean window = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[2]);
            boolean aisle = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[3]);
            boolean table = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[4]);
            double seatPrice = Double.parseDouble(seatData[5]);
            String seatFree = seatData[6];
            
            Seats info = new Seats(seatID, seatClass, window, aisle, table, seatPrice, seatFree);
            result = info;
            System.out.println(result); }
        
            reader.close();
            
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace(); }
    return result; 
    
}
```

Is this the right method or should I look at trying something else?

Any insight or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That is very good, but you're not storing what you read ? you just print it

Comment: what is `result` type ?

Comment: I know this is a bit out of scope, but why not use CSV for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reading and parsing is good, but you're not saving anything, you keep overwriting `result` with the last `info`, so your method return only one `Seats` instance, the last one, use a `List` to easily add all the Seats you create

With some improvements

- [`try_with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for autoclosing the scanner
- one row is one seat, name the class `Seat`

```
static List<Seat> read() {
    List<Seat> results = new ArrayList<>();
    File read = new File("seats.txt");
    String dataRead;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(read))) {
        while ((dataRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] seatData = dataRead.split(" ");
            String seatID = seatData[0];
            String seatClass = seatData[1];
            boolean window = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[2]);
            boolean aisle = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[3]);
            boolean table = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[4]);
            double seatPrice = Double.parseDouble(seatData[5]);
            String seatFree = seatData[6];
            Seat info = new Seat(seatID, seatClass, window, aisle, table, seatPrice, seatFree);
            System.out.println(info);
            results.add(info);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I already have a Seats class where I have tried to use a constructor to make each individual "Seat" an object. But I could not get that to work properly.

Comment: @NM15 hum, so does my code works for you or not , I don't get it ?

Comment: Sorry, yes it does work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @NM15 so you can think about voting up/accepting the answer ;) upvote and green on left left of my answer

Comment: I have tried but as my reputation is low, I don't think it shows.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson. https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/reading-csv-with-jackson-c4e74a15ddc1. See second last example.